# android AESObfuscator vs proguard

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

When setting up Android LVL I see that it uses AESObfuscator.  Do you then use Proguard?  Are they used together or one or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AESObfuscator](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Obfuscator) is an implementation of Obfuscator from Android LVL, it is used by LVL to protect sensitive licensing data stored on local device (by simply obfuscate data before storing it). This is happened at runtime.

[Obfuscation step](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) in Proguard is mainly used to obfuscate your source code to increase difficulties of decompilation from pirate. This is happened at project build time, (before compile your source dode)

We usually use both together.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html, which provides some background on both license response obfuscation (through AESObfuscator) and code obfuscation (using Proguard).

To sum things up: You will want to use both as they both address different obfuscation domains (data vs. code).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I find the developer.android website is the least helpful for someone like myself.  I could not get LVL built into my apk by following the instructions but found a better guide which got it done.  the LVL comes with sample code but no instructions on using them.  I am now weighing the usefulness of either since hacking cant be stopped and LVL seems to impact the legal users and only slows down the hacking for a little while.  I might do proguard but trying to justify why I should.  Again thanks for the reponse.

Comment: Apart from obfuscation, the main reason to use ProGuard is stripping out unnecessary classes (typically from third-party libs), which increases the memory and storage footprint of your mobile application. IMHO, this is the #1 reason to use ProGuard.